# How to check if text box is empty while pressing keys

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to check if a textbox is empty while a user is typing or deleting text in a text box. I've tried pretty much every event and a bunch of different types of checks to see if its empty but it just won't register.

What I'm doing is validating as a user modifies the input then it displays the validation text in a label below the text box like "Good", "Must be greater than 0", "Must not be left blank", "Must be numeric", and so on.

I'm using the Ghost theme if that makes any difference.

Comment: what code you have tried ?? edit your question with your code

Comment: winforms? wpf? asp.net? what's "the Ghost theme"?

Comment: Have you tried `KeyPress` event?

Comment: Sorry guys I've solved it. It was a very simple mistake. I've explained myself below.

Answer (score 0):

I'm terribly sorry but I've been up for over two days. The mistake was so small and my tired brain did not notice it. I had `false` instead of `true` on line 1. Sorry to waste your time.

```
Private Sub tbTime_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tbTime.TextChanged
    labelTimeBetween.Visible = True

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbTime.Text) = True Then
        labelTimeBetween.Text = "Musn't be empty"
        labelTimeBetween.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Return
    End If

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbTime.Text) = False And IsNumeric(tbTime.Text) = False Then
        labelTimeBetween.Text = "Numbers only"
        labelTimeBetween.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Return
    End If

    If CInt(tbTime.Text) = 0 Then
        labelTimeBetween.Text = "Must be > 0"
        labelTimeBetween.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Return
    End If

    labelTimeBetween.Text = "Good"
    labelTimeBetween.ForeColor = Color.Lime

End Sub
```

Comment: Next time simply use `If String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbTime.Text) Then` and `If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbTime.Text) AndAlso Not IsNumeric(tbTime.Text) Then` instead of the superfluous `= True` and `= False`